# Check for multiple Document Id in Firestore | Flutter

Tags: android, list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Consider I have a list of String `["id1", "id2", "id3", ...]`
Is there any way to check if these IDs are present in firestore db without a for loop.

And is it worthy of checking each ID at a time(considering the `list.length > 10,000`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too agree with @Doug Stevenson's answer.
Also you could try to write a server side function and then use that function to do the same. This will make the server work for you and will be much faster

Comment: Would you like to say more about why this solution is much faster, and provide some sort of example or a benchmark?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if a document exists, you have to read it with [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) and check the result.  If you have 10,000 documents to check, you will need to do this 10,000 times.  There is no operation for checking the existence of multiple documents.